# ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have a question about relation between member of a ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ on  a topological space  $(X,\tau)$ and a subset $K$ of $X$.

Can we cosider a  uniform  ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ as a partition on $X$? I mean if $(X,\tau)$ is topological space ,  $K \subset X$, and $\mathcal{F}$ is uniform ultrafilter , will have for $ F \in \mathcal{F}$

(1) $F \subset K$ ;

(2) $F ∩ \overline{K} = \emptyset$;

(3) $F ⊂ (\overline{K} − K)$.

Answer (score 3):

Something appears to be seriously wrong, here. It turns out that $F=\emptyset$ is the **only** set $F$ that satisfies all three given conditions--indeed, the only set $F$ satisfying any *two* of the three conditions--when $K$ is a non-empty subset of $X,$ but $F=\emptyset$ will not be a member of any filter on $X$ at all. If I understand you correctly, then, the answer is: "Definitely not."

Answer (score 1):

An ultrafilter on a set $X$ is never a partition of that set (unless you consider $\big\{\{x\}\big\}$ a partition of $\{x\}$). Assuming that $X$ has more than one point, if $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter on $X$, there is an $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}\notin\mathscr{F}$. Then $X$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ are distinct elements of $\mathscr{F}$ that are not disjoint, and $\mathscr{F}$ is not a partition of $X$.

Depending on the space $X$, the ultrafilter $\mathscr{F}$, and the compact set $K$, there might be an $F\in\mathscr{F}$ satisfying any one of your three conditions. If there is an $F\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $F\subseteq K$, then $K\in\mathscr{F}$, and there is therefore no $F\in\mathscr{F}$ satisfying (2) or (3): such an $F$ would be disjoint from $K$, and no two members of $\mathscr{F}$ are disjoint. Similarly, no $F\in\mathscr{F}$ can satisfy both (2) and (3): (3) implies that $K\in\mathscr{F}$, and (2) implies that $K\notin\mathscr{F}$.

**Added:** More concisely, $\{X\setminus\operatorname{cl}K,(\operatorname{cl}K)\setminus K,K\}$ is a finite partition of $X$, so $\mathscr{F}$ must contain exactly one of these sets. Thus, exactly one of the conditions (1)-(3) must hold for any given $\mathscr{F}$ and $K$.

Comment: (1) Do you mean that one of these three state certainly hold for any subset, not all of them?(2) is the same an uniform ultrafiltre and freeultrafiltre  on a finit set?

Comment: @fatemeh: Since $\{X\setminus\operatorname{cl}K,(\operatorname{cl}K)\setminus K,K\}$ is a finite partition of $X$, exactly one of (1)-(3) must hold. There are no free ultrafilters on a finite set. Every free ultrafilter on a countably infinite set is uniform; on uncountable sets that’s not true.